# How to run a large command file in PuTTY using automatic login in a command prompt (CMD)?

Tags: cmd.exe, putty

I am using following command in CMD to remotely open Putty (using centos 6) and execute the commands saved inside the file commands.txt saved in the computer.

```
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands.txt
```

However it is only working if the commands.txt file is about 5kb size.

Have 2 questions if someone could help, please:

a) Question 1: What should I do so it can run a commands.txt file that is bigger size?

b) Question 2: In CMD if I do 3 command lines with 3 different command files, say "commands1.txt" , "commands2.txt" and "commands3.txt" and paste all jobs below together in CMD it will open 3 putties at same time and do all things at same time.

```
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands1.txt
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands2.txt
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands3.txt
```

How do I ask CMD to execute in exact sequence instead of opening everything at same time?

This is, will open the server, execute

```
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands1.txt
```

only when finish will execute

```
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands2.txt
```

and only when finish will execute

```
putty.exe root@ip port -pw password -t -m commands3.txt
```

How to do, so it does't do all 3 jobs together at same time but one after the other in exact order I placed it?

Comment: While it's a wrong approach anyway, I do not think that, when you add three `putty.exe` calls to .cmd file, they are executed in parallel. They are executed in sequence.

Comment: Hello Prikryl, thanks for the answer, its working now. However each command it makes from the command.txt it beeps a sound, is there a way to disable this beep? Also, if the file is in the /home/ folder in the server, i tried this but it doesnt get, how could I ask him to get the command.txt file from specific folder?
plink -P port username@host < /home/command.txt 

Thank you very much !

Comment: 1) Make sure the file has unix line endings. 2) Your question was about local command file. Remote command file is a completelly different question - Though, just run it! It's also mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hi Prikryl, thanks replying. As for what I read here I need to convert the commands.txt to unix line endings and then include the quiet mode to not beep, correct? And as for the question here of this topic itself, this would open the command.txt from the root of server:

plink -P port username@host < command.txt

Would you know what do I need to include so it open command.txt from the folder /home/  ?

Thanks

Comment: No! That command reads a local file, not a file from root folder of the server!

Comment: You probably have the file both on local and remote machine. And you get confused as to where from the file is being read from. It's local redirection. There's no way that this command might be reading a remote file: `plink -P port username@host < command.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The command size limitation is imposed by the server, it's not PuTTY limitation.

---

One solution is to upload the file to the server (e.g. using `psftp` or `pscp`), grant it `x` permissions and then use PuTTY to execute it.

---

Though the right tool to automate command execution is [PLink (from PuTTY package)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

The Plink is a console application, so it can read the commands from a standard input. This way, there's no limitation, as the command are read and executed one by one (as if you type those in shell):

```
plink -P port username@host < command.txt
```